# jqgrid loadError not firing

Tags: c#, validation, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I'm using free-jqgrid v 4.15.5., MVC 5, in-line editing, Firefox and Chrome.

My issue today is that I need to implement server side validation. This will be very great to have if the validation message displays nicely.  I've cut and pasted some [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500805/asp-net-mvc-2-0-implementation-of-searching-in-jqgrid/5501644#5501644) from earlier questions.  My issue is that the `loadError` override in my `jqgrid` is not firing.  I'd love to leave it out altogether because I understand that `loadError` comes with `jqgrid` and should work by itself.  Seems not to be firing with my `loadError` in or if I leave it out?

I must have something bad in my `jqgrid` or possibly some javascript code I did not post is interfering with correct operation.  Possibly the `HandleJsonException` attribute filter isn't quite working as expected?   Any thoughts?

I use this filter and decorated my JSON method `saveGrid` with it:

```
    public class HandleJsonExceptionAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest() && filterContext.Exception != null)
            {
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode =
                    (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

                var exInfo = new List<ExceptionInformation>();
                for (Exception ex = filterContext.Exception; ex != null; ex = ex.InnerException)
                {
                    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = ex.GetType().GetProperty("ErrorCode");
                    exInfo.Add(new ExceptionInformation()
                    {
                        Message = ex.Message,
                        Source = "Validation",
                        StackTrace = ""
                    });
                }
                filterContext.Result = new JsonResult() { Data = exInfo };
                filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

I triggered the above code with this in my `saveGrid` controller:

```
throw new HttpException(400, messagetext);
```

my jqgrid:

```
      $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
            url: '/ajax/doSearch?viewid=&rowid=&isChild=false',
            mtype: 'POST',
            autowidth :true, 
            datatype: 'json',
            guiStyle: "bootstrap",
            editable: true,
            afterShowForm: function () {
                    alert('Please select row');
                    return;
                },
            editurl: "/Ajax/saveGrid?subGridViewId=&parentID=",
            loadonce: true,
            cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true },
            autoresizeOnLoad: true,
            autoResizing: { compact: false, resetWidthOrg: true },
            shrinktofit: true,
            colModel: ColModel1,
            loadError: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('hi');
                // remove error div if exist
                $('#' + this.id + '_err').remove();
                // insert div with the error description before the grid
                myGrid.closest('div.ui-jqgrid').before(
                    '<div id="' + this.id + '_err" style="max-width:' + this.style.width +
                    ';"><div class="ui-state-error ui-corner-all" style="padding:0.7em;float:left;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin-right: .3em;"></span><span style="clear:left">' +
                    decodeErrorMessage(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) + '</span></div><div style="clear:left"/></div>')
            },
            loadComplete: function () {
                alert('load complete');
                // remove error div if exist
                $('#' + this.id + '_err').remove();
            },
            caption: label,
            height: "auto",
            postData: {
                viewid: GlobalViewid,
                __RequestVerificationToken: __RequestVerificationToken
            },
            rowNum: 50,
            rowList: [16, 50, 100],
            subGrid: showSubGrid,
            // javascript function that will take care of showing the child grid
            subGridRowExpanded: showChildGrid,
            subGridOptions: {
                // expand all rows on load
                expandOnLoad: false

            },
            actionsNavOptions: {
                printicon: "glyphicon-print",
                printtitle: "Print form",
                custom: [
                    {
                        action: "print", onClick: function (options) {
                          //  window.open('Report/ReportViewer?reportname=reportf_' + GlobalViewid + '&rowid=' + options.rowid + '&reporttype=form' , 'windowName', 'width=1000, height=700, left=24, top=24, scrollbars, resizable'); 
                            window.open('Report/ReportViewer?reportname=reportf_' + GlobalViewid + '&rowid=' + options.rowid + '&reporttype=form'); 

                        },
                        hidden: noPrintButton,
                    }
                ]
            },
            pager: "#jqGridPager"
            //toppager: true
        });
```

The problem:

`loadError` never triggers so my error message is the ugly popup:

[image]

Here is the response header (noting that is 500, not the 400 I was expecting)

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcVXNlclxzb3VyY2VccmVwb3NcYXBwQnVpbGRlcldpdGhSZXBvcnRzXGFzcG5ldDQtc2FtcGxlMVxBamF4XHNhdmVHcmlk?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 02 Sep 2018 08:50:48 GMT
Content-Length: 59

And here is the response:
[{"Message":"hello","Source":"Validation","StackTrace":""}]

I tried changing the HandleJsonException attribute filter so it now returns status HTTP 400, but that didn't help.

filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode =
                        (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;

What shall I do? Thanks.

Comment: Do you get the error "[{"Message":"hello","Source":"Validation","StackTrace":""}]" during **filing** the grid with data or during **inline editing**? The method `loadError` will be used only during filing the grid with initial data. Additionally, free jqGrid 4.15.5 has **default implementation** of `loadError`. Thus I'd recommend you to remove `loadError` from your code. If the excepting will be thrown during inline editing then it's important to know how you use inline editing. The code currently posted has no such information. Which version of .NET and ASP.NET MVC you use?